# Error on Adding to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

The following code is in my implementation file:

```
NSMutableArray *courseArray;


- (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender
{
    NSDictionary *courseNames;
    if(![_txtBox.text isEqual:@""]) //if not empty
    {
        courseNames = [self retrieveCourseNamesForSemester:_txtBox.text];
        for (NSString *key in courseNames)
        {
            NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",key,[courseNames objectForKey:key]];
            _txtView.text = val;
            @try
            {
                [courseArray addObject:val];
            }
            @catch(NSException *e)
            {
                NSLog(@"Exception: %@ for value = %@", e, val);
            }
        }
    }
    [_coursePicker reloadAllComponents];
    _coursePicker.hidden=false;
    [_txtBox resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Where you see the call to `NSLog()`, I get the following error message:

```
2014-03-29 00:02:25.830 WebServiceTest[44646:60b] Exception: -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d82c30 for value = 73-522-Course Name
```

EDIT: Also, `courseArray` is populated with sample data in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    courseArray = @[@"Australia (AUD)", @"China (CNY)",
                    @"France (EUR)", @"Great Britain (GBP)", @"Japan (JPY)"];
}
```

Is there somewhere I should be defining that `courseArray` will take `NSString` objects?

Comment: `courseArray` is an immutable array. Where's your code that actually assigns a value to the `courseArray` variable?

Comment: `courseArray` was defined as `NSMutableArray` in the very first line of the code. How is it immutable? `courseArray` is populated with sample data in `viewDidLoad`, adding to the question now.

Comment: @rar The declaration is irrelevant. You are assigning an immutable array to the variable. It's not magically made mutable just because of how you declare the variable.

Comment: I understand now. Assigning it the country values made it an immutable array.

Comment: FYI - here's a hint when looking at errors like you have. When you see `__NSArrayI` - that's an internal representation for an immutable array (hence the `I`). If the error was about an actual mutable array, you would probably see `__NSArrayM`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning so that's extremely helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in viewDidLoad creates an immutable array.  You need to make a mutable copy, like this

```
(void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    courseArray = [@[@"(AUD)", @"(CNY)", @"(EUR)"] mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: Since I didn't actually need those values, I simply used `courseArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` to properly declare the array as I wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
for (NSString *key in courseNames)
{
    NSString *val = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@",key,[courseNames objectForKey:key]];
            _txtView.text = val;


    if ([CourseArray count]==0)
    {
        CourseArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:val];
    }
    else
    {
        [CourseArray addObject:val];
    }
}
```

Comment: Same exception thrown: `2014-03-29 00:23:18.823 WebServiceTest[44834:60b] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xde41590`